# Why does a channel get transmitted for a wide frequency range at night in Amplitude Modulation?

Tags: am

So I bought a radio and for some days I have been noticing that a channel with static frequency at somewhere around 880 KHz
Is tuning properly during day time but at night, the channel can be heard for a wide range of frequency, I mean , at night , the channels static frequency seems to be mixed up and the channels static frequency changes into a ranged frequency . That can be heard from almost 560KHz to 1000KHz (while 880KHz is the absolute and provides better sound quality).

I am using the radio in AM mode.
This phenomenon usually happens at night.

Now my question is, what makes this phenomenon happen?

I hope my new radio isn't faulty

Comment: What station, and where are you?

Comment: What type of radio program were you listening to, and what was its name? Some sports events and popular talk shows are simultaneously broadcast on many different radio stations.

Comment: I am in india and that was news and entertainment channel the station is almost 200kms away from my house

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your AM radio has a very wide bandwidth (low Q filters), so high power broadcast stations far from the center tuned frequency can be heard, but are drowned out by higher RF noise levels during the day.

Crystal sets with a low Q inductor coil can behave this way.